Unable to connect to application hosted behind azure front door from a VM hosted in a vnet
I have deployed a virtual machine in a dedicated private vnet and enabled outbound connections through azure firewall to external public. I have added an application rule in firewall with an entry to application URL. However, connection failed and there are no traces of deny in the logs. The access to application works when I add an entry under network rule with front door service tag.
I’m trying to understand why it works in network rule instead of an application rule.
I tried adding entry under application rule in firewalls with application URL and was expecting the connection to application works from the virtual machine.

Network rules allow or deny inbound, outbound, and east-west traffic based on the network layer (L3) and transport layer (L4). We can use a network rule when you want to filter traffic based on IP addresses, any ports, and any protocols. and Application rules allow or deny outbound and east-west traffic based on the application layer (L7). We can use an application rule when you want to filter traffic based on fully qualified domain names (FQDNs), URLs, and HTTP/HTTPS protocols.

The preferred method depends on your security requirements. If you want to allow all traffic over port 443, regardless of the protocol or destination, use a network rule. If you want to allow only specific HTTPS traffic, use an application rule. It's always better to have more granular control over the traffic allowed.
Follow the link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1165179/azure-firewall-application-rule-to-allow-https-443


Unable to connect to application hosted behind azure front door from a VM hosted in a vnet

The reason for the application connects once you add a rule in the network, the network rules allow or deny inbound, outbound, and east-west traffic based on the network layer (L3) and transport layer (L4).
We can use a network rule when you want to filter traffic based on IP addresses, any ports, and any protocols.
The Application rules allow or deny outbound and east-west traffic based on the application layer (L7). We can use an application rule when you want to filter traffic based on fully qualified domain names , URLs, and HTTP/HTTPS protocols.
The preferred method depends on your security requirements. If you want to allow all traffic over port 443, regardless of the protocol or destination, use a network rule. If you want to allow only specific HTTPS traffic, use an application rule. It’s always better to have more granular control over the traffic allowed.
Reference: Azure Firewall: application rule to allow https:443 vs network rule to allow port 443
